# B550 Gaming X V2 No Ethernet connection Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Tags: drivers

I'm having problems having set up ethernet connection for my newly installed Ubuntu after switching from Windows, thats what I get after trying to install realtek r8125 drivers in terminal after typing:

> sudo ./autorun.sh

> Check old driver and unload it.
> rmmod r8125
> Build the module and install
> warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
> The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
> You are using:           gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
> Skipping BTF generation for /home/megatron/Desktop/r8125-9.012.04/src/r8125.ko due to unavailability of vmlinux
> Warning: modules_install: missing 'System.map' file. Skipping depmod.
> DEPMOD 6.5.0-26-generic
> load module r8125
> Updating initramfs. Please wait.
> update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-26-generic
> Completed.

Can someone please give me some idea of what I'm doing wrong?